# Need some help showing the difference between two dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

So I am trying to write a function that shows the difference between two dates.

I'm currently using the following formula:

```
 =DATEDIF(D2,E2,"y")&" Years, "&DATEDIF(D2,E2,"ym")&" Months, "&DATEDIF(D2,E2,"md")
```

And this is my table:

```
+------------+-----------------+----------------------------+
| Date Hired | Date Terminated |      Length of Employment  |
+------------+-----------------+----------------------------+
| 10/11/2010 | 10/20/2010      | 0 Years, 0 Months, 9 Days  |
| 10/12/2010 | 01/28/2015      | 4 Years, 3 Months, 16 Days |
| 10/13/2010 | 05/07/2015      | 4 Years, 6 Months, 24 Days |
|            |                 |                            |
+------------+-----------------+----------------------------+
```

What I'm not sure how to do is to add a part on the function that states if a result is less than a certain time period (say 6 months), the result will display: "Less than 6 Months".

So using the example above:

```
+------------+-----------------+----------------------------+
| Date Hired | Date Terminated |      Length of Employment  |
+------------+-----------------+----------------------------+
| 10/11/2010 | 10/20/2010      | Less than 6 Months         |
| 10/12/2010 | 01/28/2015      | 4 Years, 3 Months, 16 Days |
| 10/13/2010 | 05/07/2015      | 4 Years, 6 Months, 24 Days |
|            |                 |                            |
+------------+-----------------+----------------------------+
```

How would I go about adding this into the above formula?

Comment: If you subtract dates (i.e. =b3-b2 ) the answer will be the number of days.   Use that with an IF.... That is if days less than 180 then one format, else the other.

Answer (score 1):

Just throw it into an if, checking against 6 months -

```
=IF((E2-D2)>180,DATEDIF(D2,E2,"y")&" Years, "&DATEDIF(D2,E2,"ym")&" Months, "&DATEDIF(D2,E2,"md"),"Less than 6 Months")
```